# Saving Matplotlib graphs with LaTeX fonts as eps

Tags: matplotlib, latex, jupyter-lab, eps

I am trying to make publication-quality in Jupyter-lab using matplotlib and LaTeX fonts.  I have created a simple document following instructions found here:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html

The graph was created with beautiful fonts; however, saved eps file was blank.  The same graph could be successfully saved as png, but it looked blurry when import to LaTeX even using `dpi=2400` option.  Eps files WITHOUT LaTeX fonts were sharp as a razor when imported into LaTeX file.

Suggestions?  Workarounds?

Thanks,
Radovan

PS. One workaround I found was using gnuplot and `cairolatex` terminal ... resulting *.tex file could be compiled with `Pdflatex` with excellent results.  But that a different story :-).

Comment: The tutorial renders graphs properly in the in-line graphics (jupyter-lab), but saved *.eps file is blank.  Most frustrating :-).  R>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave this another try.  At the end, it did work!  Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## reset defaults
plt.rcdefaults()

## Set up LaTeX fonts
plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "serif",
    "font.serif": ["Computer Modern Roman"],
    "font.size": 14,
    })

## Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4.5,3))

ax.plot(t, s, linewidth=3)

ax.set(xlabel=r'time $\tau_p$ [$\mu$s]', ylabel=r'voltage (mV)')
ax.set(title=r'$ E = m c^2 $')

fig.savefig("test600.png", format="png", dpi=600, bbox_inches="tight")
fig.savefig("test1200t.eps", format="eps", dpi=1200, bbox_inches="tight", transparent=True)
fig.savefig("test1200t.pdf", format="pdf", dpi=1200, bbox_inches="tight", transparent=True)

plt.show()
```

I am not sure what was wrong before.  I did different font declaration this time around.

Cheers,
Radovan